# ASP.NET Grid View Issue

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I am Newbie to NET I have been fighting with this issue from 3 days unable to solve ![[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z75bu.png)

The Data base names are Tbl_Employees,Tbl_Project
 i have to fetch Username and Project two fields from the above two tables using project_id as primary key between them and load the data in grid view .Inputs needed for Loading the Grid

[image]

Comment: You have tagged the question as c# and vb.net. The screenshot shows you are using VB.NET.

Comment: It's OK I removed the `c#` tag to prevent confusing answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm am not sure what exactly you require but it seems like the basics of grid view. Please use this excellent reference to assist your problem. http://technico.qnownow.com/tag/gridview/

Because the tag was changed from c# to vb.net I'll leave my previous answer. Please try the following. I've added a `SqlCommand`

The **VB.NET** code

```
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim DS As New DataSet
    Dim mySelectQuery As String = "SELECT dbo.Tbl_Project.Project, dbo.Tbl_Employees.User_Name FROM dbo.Tbl_Employees INNER JOIN dbo.Tbl_Project ON dbo.Tbl_Employees.Project_ID = dbo.Tbl_Project.Project_ID"
    Dim ConnString As String = "Data Source=yourSQLServer; Initial Catalog=yourDB; User Id=yourUserName; Password=yourPwd;" ''Change to you database/server specifics
    Dim myConnection As New SqlConnection(ConnString)
    Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand(mySelectQuery, myConnection)
    myConnection.Open()
    da.SelectCommand = myCommand
    da.Fill(DS,"Project")
    If Not DS.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("There were no results found. ", "No Results Found", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    Else
        gridview3.DataSource = Ds
    gridview3.DataBind()

        myConnection.Close()
    End If
```

References to connection strings
http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/sqlconnection-connection-string.aspx

Comment: Error : name messagebox is not declared and also problem with connectionstring

Comment: You can replace the messagebox with any control and you should add **your** connectionstring in place of the reference ConnString. It was just providing the reference

Comment: can u suggest me which control to use instead of messagebox

Comment: If you are using asp.net then i would suggest an <asp:Label> control. Drag the label on the html side and `<asp:Label id="label1" runat="server" />` and then in the code behind `label1.Text= "There were no results found"`

Comment: this is all using C# But my application uses VB.NET